# VBA Backward loop in a range

Tags: excel, vba, loops, count, row

I have little problem, which is;
I have the table below and what I want is to loop from right to left and count all the empty cells until the code meets a string. The amount of empty cells should be recorded in the column on the right.
https://imgshare.io/image/vba.1tPQf

The problem is that I couldn't figure out how to loop backwards and move on to the next row and start from right again. I hope you guys can help me out with this.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

In your initialization of the loop you can specify keyword "Step" to determine how your loop should behave in terms of incrementation.

```
Sub BackwardLoopInaRange()
Dim row As Integer, column As Integer
Dim startingPoint As Range: Set startingPoint = Cells(2, 7)
Dim resultColumn As Range: Set resultColumn = Range("H2")

Range("H2:H5").ClearContents  'reset counter

For row = 0 To 3
    For column = 0 To -6 Step -1
        If startingPoint.Offset(row, column).Value = vbnullsting Then
            resultColumn.Offset(row, 0).Value = resultColumn.Offset(row, 0).Value + 1
        Else: Exit For 'exits the inner loop if next cell in a row is not empty
        End If
    Next column
Next row

End Sub
```

Comment: I am trying to understand how to improve your answer looping through each column for empty cell. say, if G2 is nonempty and E2 and F2 are empty?

Comment: You could exit the inner loop if you only want to count the empty cells from right, and not between the cells with values, and continue with the next row.

Comment: Oops!! I missed that.. Thanks for the update.